# Home brew git-remote hang

Tags: git, homebrew, osx-yosemite, git-remote

My brew (homebrew) hang always on git-remote, without any message.

First I see the spinning cycle and after some seconds ... nothing > program hang. The same git-remote... symptoms on brew doctor (no cmd output - terminal title ruby ..next.. git-remote... NOTHING MORE & no spinning cycle).

Here the necessary informations:

```
> Mac OS X 10.10.3

> Xcode Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)

> gcc --version # command line tools
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix

> git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)
> which git                     
/usr/bin/git
> cd `brew --prefix`
> git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at e3edfcc gst-validate: add 1.4.0 bottle.
```

You need more informations? No problem write a comment.

I've also try to reinstall git, but without success.

```
brew reinstall git
```

**Any idea to solve this issue?**

Thanks.

Comment: How long have you waited?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Is outgoing traffic restricted by a firewall?